# Swift how to add 5 star ratings for users to vote using Firebase

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a restaurant rating app in Swift that allows its users to rate restaurants on a 5-star rating scale (just like Zomato and Yelp) .
I will be using Firebase to store each user's rating for a specific restaurant and then take the average of user ratings and display it in the app. There will be a star rating corresponding to each tableview cell (every tableview cell corresponds to a restaurant) .

However I'm stuck deeply on the project. I can't figure out how to add the user's rating to the database. My app won't require a user sign-up or login page, users can directly rate restaurants. This being said, also, how can I make sure that users can vote only once for a single restaurant? I'd appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

Here is my code so far:

```
var starsRating = 0
var starsEmptyPicName = "star" // can change to empty star picture name
var starsFilledPicName = "starfill" // can change to filled star picture name
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
let starButtons = self.subviews.filter{$0 is UIButton}
var starTag = 1
for button in starButtons {
    if let button = button as? UIButton{
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: starsEmptyPicName), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.tag = starTag
        starTag = starTag + 1
    }
}
setStarsRating(rating:starsRating)
}

func setStarsRating(rating:Int){
self.starsRating = rating
let stackSubViews = self.subviews.filter{$0 is UIButton}
for subView in stackSubViews {
    if let button = subView as? UIButton{
        if button.tag > starsRating {
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: starsEmptyPicName), for: .normal)
        }else{
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: starsFilledPicName), for: .normal)
        }
    }
  }
 }

@objc func pressed(sender: UIButton) {
    setStarsRating(rating: sender.tag)

 }
}
```

And here are my tableview functions:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
 return identifiers.count //identifiers is my big restaurants array
}



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "CellThree")
        cell.textLabel!.text = identifiers[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Here's the issue *My app won't require a user sign-up or login page*. Without having a user log in or some kind of authentication, there is no way to track it. The app needs to know who is voting and store that data in an /already_voted/ node. Then either see if that user already voted in code, or leverage Firebase Rules to deny a write if they have already voted. You can use [Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) to get some traceability but that's not really a foolproof method. It's best to create users and store their uid's.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CoreData to save if user already vote.

1. When the user rate one of the restaurant, just create a new record in core data with the restaurant's name or ID.
2. Before every vote I should check if data is existing or not. If not, user can vote.

Comment: While CoreData is very powerful, in this use case it's kind of like using a cannon to kill a fly. Why add a huge amount of overhead to store a single vote that could easily just be stored in a plist or even in userDefaults as a couple of bytes (keep reading). More importantly - and here's the real issue - the vote would only be stored on that device. If the user has multiple devices (like many of us do), they could vote over and over - which, if you think about it, they could post their login online and anyone that saw it could log into his account and vote.

Comment: @Jay Your right, it was my idea to do it without user authentication, but the best solution would be some kind of registration system.